# How to return multiple columns from multiple tables grouped with aggregate function

Tags: mysql, sql

I have three tables as follows:

```
1. Results table (containing performances)
2. Athletes table (containing athlete ids and names)
3. Events table (containing event ids and eventNames)

Results Table (sample)
+----------+-----------+---------+----------+----------+------+------------+-----------+--------+----------+---------+-----------------------+--------+----------------+------------+
| resultID | athleteID | eventID | ageGroup |   time   | wind | distHeight | implement | record | centreID | placing |      competition      | in_out |     venue      |    date    |
+----------+-----------+---------+----------+----------+------+------------+-----------+--------+----------+---------+-----------------------+--------+----------------+------------+
|      203 |    503262 |       1 | MS       | 00010.83 |  5.2 |            |           | D      | AKL      | 3       | IAAF Challenge        | out    | Arles FRA      | 2008-06-07 |
|      201 |    515092 |       1 | MS       | 00011.06 |  3.2 |            |           |        | CAN      | 6h1     | Winter Series #3      | out    | Gold Coast AUS | 2008-06-15 |
|      298 |    503262 |       1 | MS       | 00011.26 | -1.0 |            |           | D      | AKL      | 4       | TNT - Fortuna         | out    | Kladno CZE     | 2008-06-18 |
|      202 |    515092 |       2 | MS       | 00022.69 |  0.6 |            |           |        | CAN      | 4h1     | Winter Series #3      | out    | Gold Coast AUS | 2008-06-15 |
|      380 |    504550 |       2 | MS       | 00022.22 |  0.9 |            |           |        | AKL      | 6rA     | Int. Meeting Nivelles | out    | Nivelles BEL   | 2008-06-28 |
|      381 |    504613 |       2 | MS       | 00021.28 |  0.9 |            |           |        | AKL      | 2rA     | Int. Meeting Nivelles | out    | Nivelles BEL   | 2008-06-28 |
|        3 |    518131 |      33 | MS       |          |      |     077.91 | 800gm     |        | WBP      | 1Q      | Good Luck Beijing     | out    | Beijing CHN    | 2008-05-22 |
|        4 |    518131 |      33 | MS       |          |      |     079.61 | 800gm     |        | WBP      | 1       | Good Luck Beijing     | out    | Beijing CHN    | 2008-05-23 |
|      144 |    518131 |      33 | MS       |          |      |     080.51 | 800gm     |        | WBP      | 1       | Chinese Taipei Int    | out    | Taiwan TPE     | 2008-06-01 |
+----------+-----------+---------+----------+----------+------+------------+-----------+--------+----------+---------+-----------------------+--------+----------------+------------+

Event Table (sample)
+---------+---------------+
| eventID |   eventName   |
+---------+---------------+
|       1 | 100m          |
|       2 | 200m          |
|      33 | Javelin Throw |
+---------+---------------+

Athlete Table (sample)
+-----------+----------+-----------+--------+------------+--------+
| athleteID | nameLast | nameFirst | gender |    DOB     | clubID |
+-----------+----------+-----------+--------+------------+--------+
|    503262 | Lambert  | Ben       | M      | 2003-12-04 |    233 |
|    504613 | Abba     | Eric      | M      | 1991-11-03 |     20 |
|    518131 | Abbiss   | Hugh      | M      | 1992-04-03 |     57 |
+-----------+----------+-----------+--------+------------+--------+
```

I need to return the min(time) for each race event and the max(distance) for each jumping/throwing event (from the results table) along with the corresponding athlete name and event name by joining those tables respectively.

I have tried including the select items in the 'GROUP BY' list as recommended for MySql 5.7 but I end up with thousands of rows returned.

I had the following query which worked pre MySql 5.7

```
SELECT events.eventID, events.eventName, results.ageGroup, results.athleteID, MIN(results.time) AS time, MAX(results.distHeight) as distHeight, DATE_FORMAT(results.date, '%d %b %Y') as date, athletes.nameFirst, athletes.nameLast, DATE_FORMAT(athletes.DOB, '%d %b %Y') as format_DOB

FROM (
SELECT * FROM results 
WHERE results.ageGroup = 'MS' 
AND YEAR(results.date) = '2019' 
AND results.wind < 2.1 
AND results.wind != 'nwr' 
ORDER BY results.time ASC, results.distHeight DESC, results.date ASC
) as results

INNER JOIN athletes ON results.athleteID = athletes.athleteID 
INNER JOIN events ON results.eventID = events.eventID 
GROUP BY results.eventID 
ORDER BY events.eventID ASC
```

I would expect the following:

```
Event   | Result  | Athlete Name
100m    | 10.83   | Ben Lambert ...
200m    | 21.28   | Eric Abba ..
Javelin | 80.51m  | Hugh Abbiss ...
```

Any help or advice would be gratefully welcomed ...

Comment: Can you add your table definitions and sample data please.

Comment: I'n not sure how 'results.wind < 2.1' works when results.wind appears to be a string and the order by in the sub query is pointless.

Comment: 'I had the following query which worked pre MySql 5.7' It may run but it may not 'work' - the athlete will be indeterminate where an event has more than 1 result and the min(time) is not on the same row as max(distheight). That may never be the case with your data - only you know that..

Comment: Thanks for feedback ... have added some sample data

Answer (score 2):

You should join  your main query with a subquery for better performance

```
  select  events.eventID
      , events.eventName
      , results.ageGroup
      , results.athleteID
      , t.time
      , t.distHeight 
      , DATE_FORMAT(results.date, '%d %b %Y') as date
    , athletes.nameFirst
    , athletes.nameLast
    , DATE_FORMAT(athletes.DOB, '%d %b %Y') as format_DOB  
  FROM events 
  INNER JOIN result ON results.eventID = events.eventID  
  INNER JOIN athletes ON results.athleteID = athletes.athleteID 
  INNER JOIN  (

      SELECT events.eventName
          ,  results.ageGroup
          ,  MIN(results.time) AS time
          ,  MAX(results.distHeight) as distHeight
      FROM  events
      INNER JOIN result ON results.eventID = events.eventID 
      WHERE results.ageGroup = 'MS' 
      AND YEAR(results.date) = '2019' 
      AND results.wind < 2.1 
      AND results.wind != 'nwr' 
      GROUP BY events.eventName, results.ageGroup 

  ) t ON t.eventName = event.eventName 
          AND t.ageGroup = result.ageGroup
            AND ( t.time = result.time  OR t.distHeight = result.distHeight)

  ORDER BY results.time ASC, results.distHeight DESC, results.date ASC
```

Comment: Thanks for the code sample - I tried this approach but it returned thousands of rows rather than a single row for each event. I have posted some sample data tables in my original question ... might make things clearer

Comment: .. @artcoder i'm sorry ...  i have missed  a condition in join for obtain only the row matching the better records .. answer  updated ..hope is useful   .

Comment: Thanks! I tried it but still no luck. (too many rows). I'm no expert so will have to digest this and see where the tweaks need to be made.

Comment: The concept is using a subquery for better result  and join this result to the ctable with all the info  .. hope this suggestion can help

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this where the sub query draws the tables together and works out which result matches the min or max

```
select eeventname,
         case when mintime is not null then mintime
         else maxdistheight
         end as result,
         anamelast
from
(
select r.athleteid rathelteid,r.eventID reventid,r.agegroup ragegroup,
         r.time,r.distheight,
         e.eventid eeventid,e.eventname eeventname ,
         a.athleteid aathleteid,a.namelast anamelast,
         (select min(time) from results r1 where r1.eventID = r.eventid and time is not null) mintime,
         (select max(distheight) from results r1 where r1.eventID = r.eventid and time is null) maxdistheight 
from results r
join events e on e.eventid = r.eventid
left join athlete a on a.athleteid = r.athleteid
having mintime = r.time or r.distHeight = maxdistheight
) s;

+---------------+--------+-----------+
| eeventname    | result | anamelast |
+---------------+--------+-----------+
| 100m          |  10.83 | Lambert   |
| 200m          |  21.28 | Abba      |
| Javelin Throw |  80.51 | Abbiss    |
+---------------+--------+-----------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

You should test this for draws and add in any other conditions you need.

Comment: Thanks again! - tried this solution, but the database just hung while running it. Any modifications or options you think I could look at. Turning into quite a tricky one to solve.

Answer (score 0):

I came up with this that finally worked - thanks to [scaisedge](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3522312/scaisedge) for the help!

```
SELECT events.eventID, events.eventName, results.ageGroup, results.athleteID, t.distHeight, t.time, DATE_FORMAT(results.date, '%d %b %Y') as date, athletes.nameFirst, athletes.nameLast, DATE_FORMAT(athletes.DOB, '%d %b %Y') as format_DOB, competition  
FROM results 
INNER JOIN events ON results.eventID = events.eventID  
INNER JOIN athletes ON results.athleteID = athletes.athleteID 
INNER JOIN  (

  SELECT events.eventID, results.athleteID, results.resultID, results.ageGroup, MIN(results.time) AS time, MAX(results.distHeight) as distHeight
  FROM  events
  INNER JOIN results ON results.eventID = events.eventID 
  WHERE results.ageGroup = 'MS' 
  AND YEAR(results.date) = '2019'  
  GROUP BY events.eventID, time, distHeight
  ORDER BY time ASC, distHeight DESC

) t ON t.resultID = results.resultID 
    AND t.eventID = results.eventID 
        AND ( t.time = results.time AND t.distHeight = results.distHeight)
WHERE YEAR(results.date) = '2019' 
GROUP BY events.eventID, results.eventID
```